# What are the alternative ways to get list of two properties values

Tags: c#, linq

What are the alternative ways of achieving the same result produced by this:

```
myCollection.Select(item => item.FirstValue)
  .Concat(myCollection.Select(item => item.SecondValue)).ToList();
```

The scenario is a `Collection<MyClass>` named `myCollection` containing instances of the MyClass (see below). I want to create a `List<int>` instance that contains `MyClass.FirstValue` and `MyClass.SecondValue` for each item in `myCollection`.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int FirstValue { get; set; }
    public int SecondValue {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you not simply store the ints as a list in MyClass ?

Comment: You seem to have a good solution. One possible (though slightly different) alternative is `myCollection.Select(x => new[] {x.FirstValue, x.SecondValue}).SelectMany(x => x);` Note that this will alternate the values, rather than having all of one and then of the other.

Comment: What you already have looks good to me. Why do you need an alternative?

Comment: @dtb Just want alternatives for my edification

Comment: Can you clarify what you're doing this for ? storing two ints per class and then joining them into one fat list seems to loose any kind of uniqueness of the values, was this just used to demonstrate the problem ?

Comment: @RussC The code is just to demonstrate the problem. Essentially, the two values are ids. I get a list of all ids for all objects, pass them to the DataAccess layer which fetches all the objects using just one round trip to the data store.

Comment: @ƉiamondǤeezeƦ You specifically ask "using LINQ", why is that? Since you comment that you're interested in learning other ways to do this so that you can figure out which ways work best, I would think a possible answer could be "don't use LINQ here".

Comment: I have to agree with HVD, I've chosen this approach in my answer below.

Comment: @hvd You are correct. I shall update the question to remove the reference to LINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try something like this, a linqy single-pass solution:

```
private IEnumerable<int> Flatten(MyClass instance )
{
  yield return instance.Value1 ;
  yield return instance.Value2 ;
}

...

List<int> ints = myClasses.SelectMany( x => Flatten(x) ).ToList() ;
```

The `Flatten` function has to be a real method as you can't use `yield return` in a closure lest you get this error

> error CS1621: The yield statement cannot be used inside an anonymous method or lambda expression

I doubt the Linq solution is any better, simpler, more efficient, easier to understand or anything else than the obvious solution:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>() ;
foreach( MyClass item in myClasses )
{
  ints.Add(item.Value1) ;
  ints.Add(item.Value2) ;
}
```

I doubt very much that the Linq solution will be faster. If your collection of `MyClass` objects can report its size cheaply (e.g., w/o traversing the collection), you can optimize the above a bit more by pre-allocating the list to the required size:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>( 2 * myClasses.Count ) ;
foreach( MyClass item in myClasses )
{
  ints.Add(item.Value1) ;
  ints.Add(item.Value2) ;
}
```

That will save the time required to re-allocate and copy each time the list's backing store has to be resized.

Comment: I was just looking into how much linq costs after reading Jon Skeet's answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333242/how-does-linq-work-behind-the-scenes, it leaves me pretty much convinced that Linq is not the correct way for this problem. It's got a codesmell about it.

Comment: @RussC: Linq does seem to be the trendy kid on the block these days, with people pushing Linq as somehow better than anything else. Resharper is a prime sinner here. It's always trying to convince me that I should let it turn whatever into a Linq expression. Resharper should be a tool that **I** ask for advice: instead, it's a bit like the MS Office assistant, actively butting in with unwanted suggestions. But I digress.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your last comment that they are ID's I'd actually approach this from a different aspect altogether.

If you know ahead of time that you have two IDs in your Class definition, put in a property that simply returns an Array or an IEnumerable of the Type.

Using your example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int FirstValue { get; set; }
    public int SecondValue {get; set; }

    public int[] IDs
    {
        return new[] { FirstValue, SecondValue };
    }
}
```

Then to gather the ID's

```
List<int> allTheIds = new List<int>();
foreach (var mc in MyClassList)
{
    allTheIds.AddRange(mc.IDs);
}
```

This might not be perfect syntax, but I'm not on a PC at the moment to test it!

However, to my mind, this is the most sensible approach, in my experience I don't think that using Linq for linqs sake is a good idea.

That's just a personal opinion of course!